# Simplest way to prove Kakutani's Fixed-Point Theorem

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

What's the simplest way to prove Kakutani's Fixed-Point Theorem? I've read and understood a combinatorial proof of Brouwer's Fixed-Point Theorem but I don't understand the proof of Kakutani's.

Comment: What proof is your reference proof?